# Is it possible to get a response from the server using Chrome Custom Tabs in an application?

Tags: android, kotlin, chrome-custom-tabs

Please help guys, I'm making a request to the server using Chrome Custom Tabs, I get a response from the server, which is displayed in Chrome Custom Tabs, is there any way to get a response from the server or what is shown in Chrome Custom Tabs and pass this response to the application  ?  I need to get the link that is displayed in Chrome Custom Tabs (this is the server response), but there may be something else besides the link.

The server response is shown in the image (it could be a link or something), I need to get the content in the app and close Chrome Custom Tabs

I tried to get a response using registerForActivityResult, but it returned either 0 or null, but the response from the server was received and displayed in Chrome Custom Tabs.  An example usage is shown below:

```
`val builder = CustomTabsIntent.Builder() .setInitialActivityHeightPx(500) .setCloseButtonPosition(CustomTabsIntent.CLOSE_BUTTON_POSITION_END)
  val customTabsIntent = builder.build().intent
 
  val mCustomTabLauncher = registerForActivityResult<Intent, Int>(object :
  ActivityResultContract<Intent?, Int?>() {
 
  override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Intent?): Intent {
  return customTabsIntent
  }
 
  override fun parseResult(statusCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Int {
  Log.d("MyTag", "$statusCode")
  Log.d("MyTag", "${intent?.extras}")

  return statusCode
  }
 
  }) {
  // ...
  }`
```

Answer (score 0):

No. CustomTabs do not allow apps to interact with web page contents for privacy reasons.